# Grunt build script that reads xml file to determine which files are copied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gruntjs

```
copy: {
  build: {
    cwd: 'app',
    src: ['**', '!**/vendors/**', '!**src/js/*.js',],
    dest: 'dist',
    expand: true
  }
}
```

I am using grunt build scripts to build a distribution folder for the completed product. However, its not 100% automatic and dynamic. For example, I have a folder of xml content files. Yet, I don't use them all. Right now, the whole folder is copied over to the build version. Manually I have to go in and delete the xml files I don't want in the build version then run it. Or I could go into the grunt file and and tell it to ignore those files.

The problem is that I don't want to do that every time. A theoretical idea I had would be to have an xml file where I define elements to represent certain other files.

```
<bootstrap>true</bootstrap>
<extraContent>false</extraContent>
```

This would say that the file correlated to bootstrap and extraContent should or shouldn't be ignored in the build. I am trying to figure out if you could do this in grunt.

something like the following is how I see the logic playing out...

```
var bootstrap = $(xml).find("bootstrap").text()
if(bootstrap == "false"){
   var url = src/bootstrap.css
   //Here add the correlated filepath defined above to be ignored
}
```

The problem is not only writing this so grunt knows what it is, but also combining that logic with the actual "copy:{}" script I showed above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include/exclude files based on their contents you can use `filter` function for this. Examples can be found in the official documentation: https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function.

> The filter property can help you target files with a greater level of detail.

In your case this could be something like this:

```
copy: {
  build: {
    cwd: 'app',
    src: ['**', '!**/vendors/**', '!**src/js/*.js',],
    dest: 'dist',
    expand: true,

    // this filter function will copy xml files only when `bootstrap` is set to 'true'
    filter: filepath => {
      if (require('path').extname(filepath) !== 'xml')
        return true;
      const xml = require('fs').readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8');
      const json = require('xml2json').toJson(xml);
      return json.bootstrap === 'true';
    }

  }
}
```

You can then use the `process` function to copy only certain contents from specific files: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#process

> This option is passed to grunt.file.copy as an advanced way to control the file contents that are copied.

Comment: I assume filepath should be my file paths, but when I run 

grunt.registerTask('test', function(){


  const xml = require('fs').readdirSync('app/dir/content/settings.xml');

  const json = require('xml2json').toJson(xml);
  return json.settings.hasGlossary === 'true';
  });

as a test, it tells me that the first line isn't a directory

Comment: do I need a package, because it says 'module xml2json can't be found'

Comment: yes, you should install the external package with npm: `npm install xml2json --save`

Comment: is that deprecated? unlike other packages, this gives me all kinds of errors

Comment: what OS are you using?